# Querying Realm, is the query read-consistent like Oracle?

Tags: android, oracle, realm

I insert records from a ContentObserver in an Android Service like:

```
    try {
       realm.beginTransaction();
       realm.copyToRealm(sms);
       realm.commitTransaction();
    } catch (RealmException re) {
       realm.cancelTransaction();
    }
```

Then in another Service I run a JobService with the following query:

```
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmQuery<Sms> query = realm.where(Sms.class);
    RealmResults<Sms> sms = query.findAll();

    ArrayList<Sms> smsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    smsArrayList.addAll(sms);

    for (Sms sms : smsArrayList) {
       process row
       delete row
    }
```

Is the query read-consistent in point in time, like Oracle?

What happens if the query runs for some time and new data is inserted from the other Service?

I like my query to be read-consistent. The new records inserted after the query starts should not be seen or be included. Is this the case or how should I code it?

I need to be sure I process the records in the job queue properly and I want to avoid read the same job twice or mix up due to the other Service inserting.
So I'd like to do a for loop over RealmResults<< Sms>>, process it, delete the row.

Then at some point in time start the query again and process the new records.

Comment: Which transaction do you commit  if there is only reading in your code?

Comment: That's not relevant to my question, removed it.

Comment: Depends on the thread you're on. Looper threads autoupdate, non-looper threads don't.

Comment: I updated my question could you please elaborate how one should handle it, maybe with some code.

Comment: What is your Realm version? And what exactly does `process row` mean? Executing a transaction per row is pretty bad practice when it comes to Realm, causes weird issues.

Comment: Latest version. Do a Math calculation. That was just to make my point. Maybe deleteAllFromRealm(); But I'm more interested if you could get down to my initial question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On looper threads, Realms (and RealmResults and RealmObjects) are updated automatically. You can disable this by calling `setAutoRefresh` (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#setAutoRefresh-boolean-). Alternatively you can start a write transaction.

So you could do:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.setAutoRefresh(false);
// do all your reads here ...
realm.waitForChange(); // to update the instance if other threads have commit changes
```

or alternatively:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.writeTransaction(); // will wait if another write transaction is in progress
// do all your reads here ...
realm.cancelTransaction(); // no writes :-)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can't find the method writeTransaction() in code or at https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/

Comment: Sorry, I meant `beginTransaction` (which will begin a write transaction).